# Update "value relation" field problem in QGIS multi-edit mode

Tags: qgis

I tried to update a value relation field in multi-edit mode (more than one feature selected). I select a field value (from combo) for all features but it doesn´t work properly. The field is only updated for one feature. I am using QGIS 2.18.9 and two tables in SpatiaLite: one for line features and another for key-values (without geometry).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For applying edits only to a selection, you need to type the expression in the expression field and the click on the `Update Selected` button:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that´s right. But in that way I lost the combo with values (value relation field). What I am trying is to use the [multi edition](https://goo.gl/PNsy7v) capabilities and set a new value for a "value relation" field.